# Regular expression to match single dot but not two dots?

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

Trying to create a regex pattern for email address check. That will allow a dot (.) but not if there are more than one next to each other.

Should match:
test.test@test.com

Should not match:
test..test@test.com

Now I know there are thousands of examples on internet for e-mail matching, so please don't post me links with complete solutions, I'm trying to learn here.

Actually the part that interests me the most is just the local part:
test.test that should match and test..test that should not match.
Thanks for helping out.

Comment: The spec defines how you should match it http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-17 . It will be much easier to built robust regex that way than use the ad hoc solutions here that only look at the problem of 2 dots

Comment: Actually I was going through that specifications... And came to my first obstacle trying to learn regex matching a dot but not two or more next to each other.

Comment: Well it says local part is either dot-atom or quoted string, then you look up what dot-atom is which is 1 atomtext followed by optionally a dot and another atom text. Which is automatically a regex that disqualifies strings starting with dot, ending with dot, or having two or more successive dots in the middle. For simplicity, assume atomtext is just characters a-z. Then local part that allows only dot atoms is: `/^([a-z](?:\.[a-z])*)+$/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may allow any number of `[^\.]` (any character except a dot) and `[^\.])\.[^\.]` (a dot enclosed by two non-dots) by using a disjunction (the pipe symbol `|`) between them and putting the whole thing with `*` (any number of those) between `^` and `$` so that the entire string consists of those. Here's the code:

```
$s1 = "test.test@test.com";
$s2 = "test..test@test.com";
$pattern = '/^([^\.]|([^\.])\.[^\.])*$/';
echo "$s1: ", preg_match($pattern, $s1),"<p>","$s2: ", preg_match($pattern, $s2);
```

Yields:

```
test.test@test.com: 1
test..test@test.com: 0
```

Comment: second part might be `\.{1}`

Comment: it should be noted that this doesn't allow dots in the end and in the beginning of the string

Comment: and shouldn't it actually be `'/^([^\.]|([^\.]\.[^\.]))*$/'` instead of `'/^([^\.]|([^\.])\.[^\.])*$/'`? (parentheses around the `[^\.]\.[^\.])`, not just `[^\.]`)

Comment: @YakovL: It doesn't matter, in fact the inner parentheses could just be left out. Parentheses have lower precedence than the disjunction, so it is still parsed correctly.

Answer (score 5):

This seams more logical to me:

```
/[^.]([\.])[^.]/
```

And it's simple. The look-ahead & look-behinds are indeed useful because they don't capture values. But in this case the capture group is only around the middle dot.

Comment: This is true if there is a single dot anywhere in the string, it would match both examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
strpos($input,'..') === false
```

`strpos` function is more simple, if `$input' has not '..' your test is success.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^.]+\.?)+@$
```

That should do for the what comes before the `@`, I'll leave the rest for you.
Note that you should optimise it more to avoid other strange character setups, but this seems sufficient in answering what interests you

Don't forget the `^` and `$` like I first did :(

Also forgot to slash the `.` - silly me

Comment: That was fast! And basicaly answered my question. Thanks. But, is there a way to form a pattern without positive match. This will return true on test..test@ because it will match last part text@

Comment: Yep sorry about that, forgot the ^ and $, should now return true for test.test@ and false for test..test@

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question *in the title*, I'd update the RegExp by Junuxx and allow dots in the beginning and end of the string:

```
'/^\.?([^\.]|([^\.]\.))*$/'
```

which is optional `.` in the beginning followed by any number of non-`.` or [non-`.` followed by `.`].