# Regex for email not accepting more than one dot or apostrophe

Tags: .net, regex

I know there are thousands of questions regarding regex **like** [*using a regular expression to validate an email address*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) and [*regular expression to match single dot but not two dots*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673892/regular-expression-to-match-single-dot-but-not-two-dots).

I created an regex as below, which is accepting `'`(apostrophe) and `.`(dot).

```
/^[\w-\.\']{1,}\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.){1,}[\da-zA-Z-]{2,3}$/
```

But it will accept continuous double dots and continuous double apostrophe also. How do I prevent it?

E.g:

`john's.presonal@somedomain.com` is correct.

`john's..presonal@somedomain.com` is in-correct.

`john's.presonal.email@somedomain.com` is correct.

[My Fiddle Here](http://refiddle.co/11v5)

I understand looking into before hyperlink that I need to use `'/^([^\.]|([^\.])\.[^\.])*$/'`, but not sure how do I create my reg-ex!

Comment: You might be better to parse the email address twice and require it to match both regexes. Otherwise your regex is going to quickly descend into madness.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: the validation is in server side where it is an automated framework which validates `Object's Properties` and `Validation Reg-ex` associated with it. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this negative lookahead just after your `^`

```
(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))
```

**How does this work?**

`(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))` is a negative lookahead that asserts: at the present position (which is the beginning of the string), we cannot match any character followed by either two apostrophes or two dots.

**Other tweaks**

Since that is not the question, I haven't analyzed the rest of your regex. However, at a glance:

1. `{1,}` can just be written as `+`
2. Your initial `[\w-\.\']` means that an email can start with a dot (among other characters). Are you sure that is valid? If not, start your match with exactly one character from the allowable set, then only add the quantified set.
3. The `{2,3}` at the end is okay for TLDs such as `com` and `us`. But are you sure you want to exclude TLDs such as `mobi`?

**The Wheel**

For reference, here are examples of "the wheel" that has already been invented. These are two email expressions from the RegexBuddy library.

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

RFC2822:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Comment: This was my first reg-ex of my life :) Thanks for pointing it out. Will update my regex :). It works as of now that's magical for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Idothisallday Wow, if this is your first regex ever, you're doing great! You'll be a pro in no time. Thanks for your feedback. FYI, added two regexes from the RB library for reference, but it sounds like you want to do your own thing. :)

Comment: I was actually writing it in [regex101](http://regex101.com/) where these guys highlighted that `\w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Rest I was picking up after little googling :P

Comment: My final regex is as you suggested `/^(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))[\w-\.\']+\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.)+[\da-zA-Z-]{2,5}$/`. I have tried your suggestion 1 and 3. But Not sure how to try for 2. I am not getting that work. Can you please help. Is this wrong? `/^(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.)+[\da-zA-Z-]{2,5}$/`

Comment: Is this correct `/^(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))[A-Za-z0-9-\.\'\-\_]+\@([\da-zA-Z-]{1,}\.)+[\da-zA-Z-]{2,5}$/`

Comment: @Idothisallday Briefly, some small corrections on the regex in your comments `(?i)^(?!.*(?:''|\.\.))[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9.'_]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,5}$` The `(?i)` saves `A-Z` space by going to case-insensitive. The `{1,}` is replaced by a `+` The initial `[a-z0-9]` ensures that your first character is not a dot etc (if you want that) The `\d` in .NET can be Arabic or Thai digits so I replaced it with `0-9`, also removed it from the TLD. Moved up the `-` at the front of the character classes for clarity, also the `.'-_` dont need to be escaped in a charclass so removed `\`. You can tweak forever!

Answer (score 1):

A regex to match every valid email is [very complicated](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

You should use something like [`filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var.php) in PHP or [`[NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in Objective-C.